# Does mosquitto_pub convert a binary file to ASCII?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am quite new to MQTT protocol and I am sorry if my question sounds stupid. I am publishing an image from a device and when I subscribe to it on CLI I can see some characters which are not in the binary format. So my question is when the image is published does it by default get converted to ASCII format and then sent or is it received in the ASCII format or some other format?

The publish command I am giving is:

mosquitto_pub --cafile /home/pi/nirupama/rootCA.pem --cert /home/pi/nirupama/certificate.pem --key /home/pi/nirupama/private.pem -h xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t $aws/things/raspberry-pi/shadow/update -i mqtt_test -f /media/webcam/picture.jpg

The subscribe command is:

mosquitto_sub --cafile /home/pi/nirupama/rootCA.pem --cert /home/pi/nirupama/certificate.pem --key /home/pi/nirupama/private.pem -h xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t $aws/things/raspberry-pi/shadow/update -i mqtt_test1

Comment: Update your question with exactly how you are publishing and subscribing to the messages you are sending. But MQTT payloads are always just raw byte arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was answered on the MQTT mailing list by JP Mens:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mqtt/MIwf0-Bi9yM

The answer is that MQTT in a binary protocol and they payloads are not converted to ASCII or any other text format. You should indeed be able to send binary image payloads without corruption.

Comment: Got what I wanted to know. Thank you!