# How to upload a image file from client to mqtt broker

Tags: mqtt

How to upload a image file from client to mqtt broker.
What would be the best option Base64 conversion or multi part form data ?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190872/does-mosquitto-pub-convert-a-binary-file-to-ascii/36197255#36197255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what's consuming the messages.

But since MQTT message payloads are just byte arrays, you don't actually need to encode the image at all, just send the raw bytes to the topic.

Comment: There was a question and answers about sending images/binary payloads on the MQTT Google group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mqtt/MIwf0-Bi9yM/FvFFpcPRKAAJ